# How to publish on Facebook timeline, more than 60 days after user gives permission like Thunderclap.it

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

On thunderclap.it, users choose a cause to support, give post permissions (publish_actions) and when the cause "expires" it automatically posts to all the pledged users' feed at the same time.

This is ok for any cause up to 60 days (long-live access token).

How is it possible for causes that expire after 60 days?
For example, this one expires and will auto-post a message on your wall in 166 days.

https://www.thunderclap.it/projects/982-lights-of-the-city-by-tpr

Is it possible with the current access_token?

What needs to be done to achieve this functionality (auto-post to user's feed, regardless of user being online/offline and regardless when his last login at the app was)?

Everything I have read suggest this is possible for up to 60-days after the user gives the permission. And in order to extend this time you need the user to re-use the app (get new access token).

So, how does this work on thunderclap.it ?

Comment: Once a user has given an app publishing permission, the _app_ access token can also be used to publish on behalf of that user (exchanging `/me/…` for `/userid/…` of course).

Comment: Thanks! that sounds indeed very helpful and that it'd work.
For other people looking into the same problem:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/publishing-with-app-token/

Explains how to issues and use an app access token.